# Adding hyphen between specified prefix and suffix

Tags: regex, google-sheets

[image]

Suppose `prefix={mr,ms}` and `suffix={junior,senior}`.

I wish to add a hyphen after the specified prefix and before the specified suffix.

Individually, I can do something like `=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"mr","mr-")` and `=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"senior","-senior")`, but is there a way to do everything above with a single formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use capture groups to simplify that. Here are two nested replaces, one for the `ms` and `mr` case, and one for the `junior` and `senior` case:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A38,"^(mr|ms)","$1-"),"(junior|senior)$","-$1")
```

Explanation `"^(mr|ms)"`:

- `^` - start of string (this avoids false hits such as msmiria**mr**eich)
- `(mr|ms)` - capture group with ORed combination of all prefixes
- reference capture group with `$1`

Explanation `"(junior|senior)$"`:

- `(junior|senior)` - capture group with ORed combination of all postfixes
- `$` - end of string
- reference capture group with `$1`

Cramming the two regexes into one is possible, but you would get a rather long regex because you have to consider permutation of (with/without prefix) and (with/without postfix).

Comment: Suppose prefix can be `xx` and `x`, but not `xxx` 
So xdavid = x-david and xxdavid = xx-david, but xxxdavid would remain xxxdavid.
`"^(x|xx)"` would cause xxxdavid to be x-xxdavid and `"^(xx|x)"` would cause xxxdavid to be xx-xdavid.
Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: It would be possible with a negative lookahead such as `"^(mr|ms|xx(?!x))"`, however, the Google regex does not support that. If the names are capitalized such as `XxDavid` you could support that case with a case-sensitive regex pattern.